# print all triples into RDF files

Tags: php, semantic-web

i'm using rdfapi-php library and trying to open my RDF file.

Here are the code edited from the tutorial to show the content parsed into the way the library explain.

```
//include RDF API
define("RDFAPI_INCLUDE_DIR", "C:/OpenSA/Apache/htdocs/rdf_api/api/");
include(RDFAPI_INCLUDE_DIR . "RDFAPI.php");

// Filename of an RDF document
$base="example1.rdf";

// Create a new MemModel
$model = ModelFactory::getDefaultModel();

// Load and parse document
$model->load($base);
// Get Iterator from model
$it = $model->getStatementIterator();

// Traverse model and output statements
while ($it->hasNext()) {
   $statement = $it->next();
   echo "Statement number: " . $it->getCurrentPosition() . "<BR>";
   echo "Subject: " . $statement->getLabelSubject() . "<BR>";
   echo "Predicate: " . $statement->getLabelPredicate() . "<BR>";
   echo "Object: " . $statement->getLabelObject() . "<P>";
}
```

that is the output

```
Statement number: 0
Subject: http://www.w3.org/Home/Lassila
Predicate: http://description.org/schema/Creator
Object: e85740

Statement number: 1
Subject: e85740
Predicate: http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#type
Object: http://description.org/schema/Person
```

My problem is that in the variable $base i will have an array with the name of all my RDF files. How i can edit the script to get the content of all the file of the array and after that print every RDF triple?

Regards

Comment: what do you want to do here? do you want to print all the content of example1.rdf ?

Comment: Hi Swamy, thx for the reply. i want the while looping a variable  $array that contain a list of all my file like $array = array{'file1.rdf, file2.rdf ...} and then print all their contents in one loop and not in a single loop for file. I tried some solution but none works.